# Owl Carousel change content of the element on click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, owl-carousel

I have a problem with owl carousel and till now I don't have any ideas how to fix it.
So on the image 1 you can see the normal behaviour of the slider. On the second one you will see the extended functionality of it. The idea is very simple, when user click on the element, he should  expand it, but when the element is expanded all other element goes to 2 rows and I don't want to happen.

Image 1
[image]

Image 2
[image]

also Source code of one element

```html
 <div class="element box-shadow">
                    <div class="child">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">
                                <span>05.</span>
                                <h3>Graphic Designer</h3>
                                <p class="inventive">Inventive Studio</p>
                                <p class="view-more">View more <img src="assets/images/view-more.svg" /></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 portfolio-image" >
                                <img src="assets/images/inventive-small-img.png" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="parent hidden">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">
                                            <div class="row " style="margin-bottom: 15px;" >
                                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
                                                    <img src="assets/images/inventive-small-img.png" style="width:34px" class="rounded-circle">
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-9 text no-padding" >
                                                    <h3>Graphic Designer</h3> 
                                                    <p class="inventive">Inventive Studio</p> 
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 social-el" style="padding-left:0;">
                                            <div class="stars">
                                                <img class="mr-2" src="assets/images/full_star.svg" />
                                                <img class="mr-2" src="assets/images/full_star.svg" />
                                                <img class="mr-2" src="assets/images/half_star.svg" />
                                                <img class="mr-2" src="assets/images/empty_star.svg" />
                                                <img src="assets/images/empty_star.svg" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <img src="assets/images/inventive-studio-img.png" class="img-fluid">
                                    <div class="content">
                                        <p >Designing and producing catalogs, sales sheets, proposals, scenario illustrations, brochures, posters, custom displays for trade shows and in-house exhibits and all others items.</p>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                                                <a class="view-less" href="#"><img src="assets/images/view-more.svg"/> View Less</a>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                                                <div class="stars">
                                                    <img src="assets/images/Facebook.svg"/>
                                                    <img class="mr-10" src="assets/images/twitter.svg"/>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

also will share and jquery code

```js
$(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
        margin:10,
        loop: true,
        autoWidth: true,
        items:3,
        rewind: true,
        autoplay: true,
        responsiveClass:true,
    });

    $('.work').each(function(i, el) {
        $parent = $(el);
        $('.element', $parent).each(function(i, item) {
            $element = $(item)
            $element.on('click', function(e) {
                
                $current = $(this)
                console.log($current)
                if ($('.parent', $current).hasClass('hidden')) {
                    $('.parent', $current).removeClass('hidden');
                    $current.addClass('expand-element');
                    $current.css('border-radius', 10)
                    $('.child', $current).addClass('hidden');
                } else {
                    $current.removeClass('expand-element');
                    $('.parent', $current).removeClass('visible').addClass('hidden');
                    $current.css('border-radius', 20)
                    $('.child', $current).removeClass('hidden');
                }
            })
        })
    })
```

Comment: Can you make this code executable so that can see how it acually work..?

Comment: ok will put it in jsfiddle and will share with you